# iOS - App become sluggish after updating on iOS 10

Tags: ios

I created one application, where I used UICollection View in one of my Dashboard. My application is working smoothly in iOS version 8, 9 but when I run it on iOS 10 or above Application become slow. I used Time profiler in Xcode instruments to check at which point app is taking maximum time .

I found `[scrollCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath]` where it is taking too much time .

Please tell anybody if have any solution for my problem .
My code is :-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)scrollCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier  = @"Cell";

    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[scrollCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    RigObject *object = [rigData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.rigNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.rigNumber];
    cell.rigTemp.text = object.rigTemp;
    cell.rigTimer.text = object.rigTimer;
    cell.slotUsed.text = object.slotUsed;
    cell.slotFree.text = object.slotFree;
    cell.rigStatus.text = object.rigStatus;
    cell.shockType.text = object.shockType;
    cell.totalTask.text = object.completedTask;
    cell.pendingTask.text = object.pendingTask;
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:object.updatedDate]/3600;
    if (interval < 8) {
        cell.rigTimer.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if (interval > 8 && interval < 16) {
        cell.rigTimer.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if ( interval > 16) {
        cell.rigTimer.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    if ([object.rigStatus isEqualToString:@"Not Working"]) {
        cell.rigView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        cell.rigView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];

        [cell.rigStatus setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.rigView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
        [cell.rigStatus setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0491 green:0.4404 blue:0.1049 alpha:1]];
    }

    cell.tripDescription.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.tripDescription addTarget:self
               action:@selector(tripDescriptionClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.rigView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: post the code inside collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)scrollCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    static NSString *identifier  = @"Cell";
    
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[scrollCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    
    RigObject *object = [rigData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.rigNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.rigNumber];

    cell.rigView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: I added the code please look once .

Comment: looking at it :) It would be helpful if you can add it as a part of your question reading it in comments is bit tough

Comment: i added the code in question . Please look

Comment: I dont find any CPU intensive work in cellForItemAtIndexPath i dont find any reason why dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier might take more time :o Can you try dumb idea of mine, 1. remove the static variable identifier declaration from inside cellForItemAtIndexPath and either declare it outside once or hardcode the string in dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier. I know that won't much make sense please try it once though anyway declaring variable inside cellForItemAtIndexPath is wrong

Comment: Its working perfectly in iOS 8, 9 only creating the issue in iOS 10 . I tried it but no success

Comment: If anyone facing the same type of problem in iOS 10 . It would be helpful if anyone provide the solution .

Comment: Have you tried disabling prefetching, its a new ios 10 only feature of UICollectionview.

collectionview.isPrefetchingEnabled?

Comment: I tried collectionview.isprefetchingEnabled = false; in viewDidLoad but no success.

Comment: Anyone faced the same kind of issue in UICollection view ?

Comment: I didn't get any solution for this problem . Might be after OS update no-one has worked with UICollectionView . I didn't get any code,example related to prefetching enabling .

Comment: I found the solution of problem by running time profiler in Xcode . Issue was because of external Font file that i was using in my project . iOS 10 is not supporting this specific font .